# if and else statement mixed up

Tags: php, if-statement

I am doing the following if else statement below but number (**//1)** and number (**//4)** get executed at the same time, I am finding it abit hard to understand why.

```
    <?php

    //1

    if($a == 1 && count($b) == 0) {

 // do this
    }

//2
elseif ($a == 1 && count($b) > 0)   {
// do that

}

//3
if($a== 0 && count($b) == 0) {

// do a different thing
}

//4
else {
// do the last thing

}
?>
```

I have done this and it works but i think the should be a more suitable way for not using elseif for this.

```
else if($a== 0 && count($b) > 0) {
 // do the last thing
}
```

Comment: Is `$a` getting manipulated in anyway in the first if/else block?

Comment: Don't you get a parse error `$$`?

Comment: @Pitchinnate nothing. because `$a` is a function which returns true or false.

Comment: @Nouphal.M not error is just that the first `if` and last `else` are showing at the same thing which shouldn't happen

Comment: @Pitchinnate `$$idea->getideas() == 0` thats what `$a == 0 ` represent in this question. so the function name is `getideas`

Comment: Your third block should elseif I guess, or it will execute, no matter if first if or elseif executes too

Comment: Then you need to change that in the question above because a function can evaluate differently each time. By just replacing the function with `$a` isn't an accurate representation because it isn't a set value.

Comment: @RoyalBg i think the should be a way to avoid doing an elseif in this case because the second if output the same results abit different from the last `else`

Comment: Put `echo 'a: ' . $$idea->getideas() . '<br>';` before each if statement to see if it is evaluating the same value both times.

Comment: @user3057514 but the block will stop execution once it finds true statement, so no mater how much equal elseif's or else's are therem only one will execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to do this...

```
if ($a == 1 && count($b) == 0) {
// do this

}
//2
elseif ($a == 1 && count($b) > 0) {
// do that

}
elseif ($a== 0 && count($b) == 0) {
// do a different thing

}
else {
// do the last thing

}
```

The reason they get executed at the same time is that... Well technically they're not executed at the same time since it's procedural, but they both get executed because they are both different if else conditions. If you want only 1 execution, you should combine them :)

Comment: Thanks chris_techno25

Answer (score 2):

> but number (//1) and number (//4) get executed at the same time

It's because you don't have `else` before the if on //3

```
//3
if($a== 0 &&
```

Change to `elseif($a== 0 &&`

At the moment you have two separate IF conditions

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing brace after your first `if`.

Also, you have a weird operator inside your first condition : `$$`. Maybe you intended to type `&&`?

Comment: sorry had to put that in the question but this is not the reason

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = 10;

if ($a == 5) {
  echo 'ok';
} elseif ($a == 10) { // $a is equal to 10, so it executes;
  echo 'not_ok';
}

if ($a > 20) {
   echo 'ok_ok';
} else { // $a is not >20 so else statement executes
   echo 'not_not';
}
```

final result: `not_oknot_not`

If you are performing such tests on one and the same assignee, but different values, you might not want to execute more than one?

I guess you need elseif where third block is if

```
if ($a == 5) {
  echo 'ok';
} elseif ($a == 10) { // $a is equal to 10, so it executes and stops the block;
  echo 'not_ok';
} elseif ($a > 20) {
   echo 'ok_ok';
} else { // $a is not >20, but the block was stopped on first elseif
   echo 'not_not';
}
```

produces `not_ok`

Even if you move the else statement after the first elseif block as was suggested

```
if ($a > 20) {
   echo 'ok_ok';
}
```

will execute, and if it's true, it will produce result, which again will result in double result